# Removing a specific character in the string from column of the data frame in R

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have a dataframe L with column price that I store in variable pr. I want to remove the "$" from the price column and then turn it into numeric. How do I do this please? I tried as followed.

This is my column before:

[columnBefore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CseO5.png)

I tried this code:

```
pr = L$price
pr <- gsub("$", "", pr)
pr
```

But, instead of removing "$", it adds "" to the data

[columnAfter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5WqG.png)

Could you please let me know how I can do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$` is an end of string position in regex. Escape it, or use in a bracket expression like `[$]`, or just use `fixed=TRUE` argument with your `gsub` code.

Comment: Ohhh thank you so much. Yes, it works with [$] :-)

Comment: I think `gsub("$", "", pr, fixed=TRUE)` is more "idiomatic" since you do not even need to use a regex.

Comment: Thank you I will try this as well :)